# Как узнать об использовании видеокарты приложением?

Tags: c++, windows, 3d, gpu

Необходимо при запуске 3д приложения выполнять код. Думал ставить хуки на создание окон d3d и opengl, но потом увидел в диспетчере вот такое

> [image: Использование графического процессора]

Подскажите функцию или пример, как можно вынуть данную информацию.

Comment: Для винды, я думаю, можно через WMI достать. А вот в c++ точно нет встроенных средств для вашей задачи.

Comment: Благодарю за наводку. Но боюсь моих знаний вряд ли хватит это осилить, слишком серьезная вещь - этот WMI :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функциональность просмотра информации о работе GPU в диспетчере - новинка Windows 10 ([подробнее](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/directx/2017/07/21/gpus-in-the-task-manager/)). Для того, чтобы она работала, необходим графический адаптер с поддержкой WDDM 2.0. Информация берется, по-видимому, из специального счетчика производительности "*GPU Engine*", который имеет для каждого процесса, использующего графику, несколько экземпляров с именем вида:

> pid_5036_luid_0x00000000_0x00009F54_phys_0_eng_3_engtype_3D

Из этой строки можно извлечь информацию о том, к какому процессу и графическому движку он относится. У счетчика два значения, *Utilization Percentage* и *Running time*. *Utilization Percentage* у меня почему-то всегда нулевое, наверное, самый простой способ найти процессы, использующие 3D-графику - это отфильтровать те, у которых *Running time* больше нуля.

Для работы со счетчиками производительности можно использовать WMI или [PDH-функции](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373214(v=vs.85).aspx). Пример вывода процессов, использующих 3D Engine, с помощью PDH-функций:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//для работы со счетчиками производительности:
#include <pdh.h>
#include <pdhmsg.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "pdh.lib")

//для получения информации о процессах:
#include "psapi.h"
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

const PWSTR COUNTER_OBJECT = L"GPU Engine"; //Имя счетчика производительности

/*Вывод имени процесса по его PID*/
void PrintProcessName(int pid){

    HANDLE hProcess;
    DWORD charsCarried=0;
    TCHAR PrName[MAX_PATH]=L"";

    hProcess= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,pid);
    if (hProcess) 
    {
        charsCarried=MAX_PATH;                          
        if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess,0,PrName,&charsCarried)==0){
            StringCchCopy(PrName,MAX_PATH,L"Unknown process");
        }

        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    else StringCchCopy(PrName,MAX_PATH,L"Unknown process");

    PathStripPath(PrName);
    wprintf(L"%s",PrName);
}

void main(void)
{
    PDH_STATUS status = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    LPWSTR pwsCounterListBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD dwCounterListSize = 0;
    LPWSTR pwsInstanceListBuffer = NULL;
    DWORD dwInstanceListSize = 0;
    LPWSTR pTemp = NULL;

    HQUERY hQuery = NULL;
    HCOUNTER hCounter = NULL;

    DWORD dwFormat = PDH_FMT_LONG; 
    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE ItemBuffer;
    wchar_t buffer[1000];
    wchar_t * p;

    // Determine the required buffer size for the data. 
    status = PdhEnumObjectItems(
        NULL,                   // real-time source
        NULL,                   // local machine
        COUNTER_OBJECT,         // object to enumerate
        pwsCounterListBuffer,   // pass NULL and 0
        &dwCounterListSize,     // to get required buffer size
        pwsInstanceListBuffer, 
        &dwInstanceListSize, 
        PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD,     // counter detail level
        0); 

    if (status == PDH_MORE_DATA) 
    {
        // Allocate the buffers and try the call again.
        pwsCounterListBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc(dwCounterListSize * sizeof(WCHAR));
        pwsInstanceListBuffer = (LPWSTR)malloc(dwInstanceListSize * sizeof(WCHAR));

        if (NULL != pwsCounterListBuffer && NULL != pwsInstanceListBuffer) 
        {
            status = PdhEnumObjectItems(
                NULL,                   // real-time source
                NULL,                   // local machine
                COUNTER_OBJECT,         // object to enumerate
                pwsCounterListBuffer, 
                &dwCounterListSize,
                pwsInstanceListBuffer, 
                &dwInstanceListSize, 
                PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD,     // counter detail level
                0); 

            if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
            {                

                wprintf(L"\nProcesses using 3D engine:\n\n");

                // Walk the instance list. The list can contain one
                // or more null-terminated strings. The list is terminated
                // using two null-terminator characters.
                for (pTemp = pwsInstanceListBuffer; *pTemp != 0; pTemp += wcslen(pTemp) + 1) 
                {
                    p = wcsstr(pTemp,L"engtype_3D");
                    if(p==NULL)continue;//отфильтровать записи, не относящиеся к 3D Engine

                    //построим путь к запрашиваемому значению счетчика...
                    StringCchCopy(buffer,1000,L"\\GPU Engine(");
                    StringCchCat(buffer,1000,pTemp);
                    StringCchCat(buffer,1000,L")\\Running time");

                    //создадим запрос...
                    status = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &hQuery);
                    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"PdhOpenQuery failed with 0x%x\n", status);
                        continue;
                    }

                    //добавим счетчик в запрос...
                    status = PdhAddCounter(hQuery, buffer, 0, &hCounter);
                    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"PdhAddCounter failed with 0x%x\n", status);
                        continue;
                    }

                    //получаем данные...
                    status = PdhCollectQueryData(hQuery);
                    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"PdhCollectQueryData failed with 0x%x\n", status);
                        continue;
                    }

                    status = PdhCollectQueryData(hQuery);
                    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"PdhCollectQueryData failed with 0x%x\n", status);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Format the performance data record.
                    status = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(hCounter,
                        dwFormat,(LPDWORD)NULL,&ItemBuffer);

                    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != status)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"PdhGetFormattedCounterValue failed with 0x%x\n", status);
                        continue;
                    }                                       

                    int pid=0;  

                    //выведем информацию о процессе, если Running time > 0
                    if(ItemBuffer.longValue > 0){                       

                        swscanf(pTemp,L"pid_%d",&pid);  //парсим PID из имени счетчика                                              
                        PrintProcessName(pid);
                        wprintf(L", PID: %d - ", pid);
                        wprintf(L"Usage time: %d\n",(int)ItemBuffer.longValue);                     
                    }
                    PdhCloseQuery(hQuery);

                }
            }
            else 
            {
                wprintf(L"Second PdhEnumObjectItems failed with %0x%x.\n", status);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            wprintf(L"Unable to allocate buffers.\n");
            status = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        wprintf(L"\nPdhEnumObjectItems failed with 0x%x.\n", status);
    }

    if (pwsCounterListBuffer != NULL) 
        free (pwsCounterListBuffer);

    if (pwsInstanceListBuffer != NULL) 
        free (pwsInstanceListBuffer);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

[image: Пример вывода]

---

На системах до Windows 10 (или если нет поддержки данной функциональности у адаптера, и, как следствие - нет этого счетчика), можно использовать функцию [EnumProcessModules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631(v=vs.85).aspx) для получения загруженных DLL процесса. Если среди них есть библиотеки Direct 3D - **d3d9.dll**, **d3d10.dll**, **d3d11.dll** и т.п., можно считать, что процесс использует 3D-графику.